# Data transformation in Python. Is there a better way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Below is a code snippet of the task I have to perform. I want to have the best time complexity possible for this task. Is there a library or a better implementation?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"v_id": [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,5,5], \
                    "date": ['01-01-2017', '02-01-2017', '03-01-2017',\
                    '02-01-2017', '03-01-2017',
                    '01-01-2017', '02-01-2017', '03-01-2017', '04-01-2017',\
                    '05-01-2017','04-01-2017'],\
                    "value":[0.9,1.5,2.4,7.1,0.4,1.8,5.1, 6.4, 7.7, 3.9, 0.3]})

dim1, dim2 = df1.v_id.unique(), df1.date.unique()
dim1_dict, dim2_dict = dict(zip(dim1, list(range(0, len(dim1))))), \
                        dict(zip(dim2, list(range(0, len(dim2)))))

value_result, date_result = np.empty((len(dim1), len(dim2)), dtype=object),\
                            np.empty((len(dim1), len(dim2)), dtype=object)


for i in range(0, len(df1)):
    date_result[dim1_dict.get(df1.loc[i].v_id), \
    dim2_dict.get(df1.loc[i].date)] = df1.loc[i].date
    value_result[dim1_dict.get(df1.loc[i].v_id), \
    dim2_dict.get(df1.loc[i].date)] = df1.loc[i].value
```

The dataframe **df1** looks like this:
[image]

My goal is to get the **date_result** (v_id *x* date)

```
array([['01-01-2017', '02-01-2017', '03-01-2017', None, None],
       [None, '02-01-2017', '03-01-2017', None, None],
       ['01-01-2017', '02-01-2017', '03-01-2017', '04-01-2017', None],
       [None, None, None, '04-01-2017', '05-01-2017']], dtype=object)
```

& **value_result** matrix (v_id *x* value).

```
array([[0.90000000000000002, 1.5, 2.3999999999999999, None, None],
       [None, 7.0999999999999996, 0.40000000000000002, None, None],
       [1.8, 5.0999999999999996, 6.4000000000000004, 7.7000000000000002,
        None],
       [None, None, None, 0.29999999999999999, 3.8999999999999999]], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could perform this calculation using [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"v_id": [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,5,5], 
                    "date": ['01-01-2017', '02-01-2017', '03-01-2017',
                    '02-01-2017', '03-01-2017',
                    '01-01-2017', '02-01-2017', '03-01-2017', '04-01-2017',
                    '05-01-2017','04-01-2017'],
                    "value":[0.9,1.5,2.4,7.1,0.4,1.8,5.1, 6.4, 7.7, 3.9, 0.3]})

date_result = (df1.assign(date2=df1['date'])
                  .pivot_table(columns='date', index='v_id', 
                               values='date2', aggfunc='first').values)
value_result = df1.pivot_table(columns='date', index='v_id', 
                               values='value', aggfunc='first').values

print(date_result)
print(value_result)
```

yields a `date_result` of:

```
array([['01-01-2017', '02-01-2017', '03-01-2017', None, None],
       [None, '02-01-2017', '03-01-2017', None, None],
       ['01-01-2017', '02-01-2017', '03-01-2017', '04-01-2017', None],
       [None, None, None, '04-01-2017', '05-01-2017']], dtype=object)
```

and `value_result` of

```
array([[ 0.9,  1.5,  2.4,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  7.1,  0.4,  nan,  nan],
       [ 1.8,  5.1,  6.4,  7.7,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,  0.3,  3.9]])
```

---

Note that `value_result` is a NumPy array with floating-point dtype, and that the missing values are represented by `nan`s not `None`. You can convert it to a NumPy array with `object` dtype and missing values of `None` by using

```
value_result = np.where(pd.isnull(value_result), None, value_result)
```

which yields

```
array([[0.9, 1.5, 2.4, None, None],
       [None, 7.1, 0.4, None, None],
       [1.8, 5.1, 6.4, 7.7, None],
       [None, None, None, 0.3, 3.9]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thanks yaar,,,, u save me